# getting error: subprocess-exited-with-error while installing segmentation package from github

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, conda, ultralytics

I am trying to install a package from github using the following command:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything.git
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
      Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything.git 'C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ffy6qkpp'
      error: RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 3 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream
      error: 3805 bytes of body are still expected
      fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
      fatal: early EOF
      fatal: index-pack failed
      fatal: could not fetch 6b0759587aa5756e66a13ef034c6bcdd76a885f5 from promisor remote
      warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
      You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
      and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
    
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything.git 'C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ffy6qkpp' did not run successfully.
      exit code: 128
      
      See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything.git 'C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ffy6qkpp' did not run successfully.
    exit code: 128
    
    See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried to:

- upgrade pip
- upgrade python version
  as suggested in some other websites, but the problem still persists.

Please help me to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just `pip install segment-anything` to install from https://pypi.org/project/segment-anything/#files ?